# Как в PHP задать время выполнения конкретной функции, оставив глобальный time_limit(0)

Tags: php, curl

Скрипт работает на сервере постоянно, как демон с `set_time_limit(0);`, и выполняет запросы через curl с прокси. Иногда запрос выполняется слишком долго и его надо остановить, сменить прокси и повторить.

Возможно ли ограничить время выполнения конкретного запроса, не трогая глобальный `set_time_limit`? Если да, то как?

Comment: Почти уверен, что у курла есть возможность задать тайауты запроса

Comment: `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` - Максимально позволенное количество секунд для выполнения cURL-функций. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php